# Find Jordan form of powers of Jordan matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a Jordan matrix with blocks $J_5(0),J_6(0)$ with $J_m(\lambda)$ having size $m\times m$. I am to find the Jordan form of $A^2$. Since $A$ is in Jordan form and powers of $A$ have the same transition matrices $P$ as $A$, I think this implies $A^2$ must be in Jordan form, and to find it I have no choice but to calculate the squares of $J_5(0),J_6(0)$. Is this correct, and is there an easier way?

Comment: Observe that in $\;J_5(0)\;$ you already have $\;1\;$ in the entry $\;1-3\;$ , so it can't be in Jordan normal form.

Comment: Are you asking only about Jordan forms of powers, or also about the posibly revised transition matrices?

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras I don't understand - $J_5(0)$ is basically by definition in Jordan form - why are you saying it isn't?

Comment: @hardmath both!

Comment: @linalg Sorry about that. It should have been $\;J_5(0)^2\;$ .

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras, okay. So what do I do here?

Comment: But the Jordan form of $J_5(0)^2$ has blocks $J_4(0)$ and $J_1(0)$...

Comment: @Servaes and this I am to find by just calculating?

Comment: Do you know/have you calculated what $J_5(0)^2$ looks like? All you need to do then is move the first column to the last. This is (part of) what makes Jordan forms so nice.

Comment: For me this is $$\;J_5(0)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\;$$meaning: a block of size $\;5\;$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\;\lambda=0\;$ . Is this correct?

Comment: @Servaes what do you mean move the first column to last?

Comment: Hint: consider the eigenvalues of $J_m(\lambda)$.