# Conclude about the characteristic, minimal polynomials and eigenvalues of matrix $A^2$ from $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

We have a matrix $A : 7x7$ with a minimal polynom: 
$$
m(t) = (t - \lambda)^3
$$

Also, we know that $A$ is not a Nilpotent matrix.

The rank of $A-\lambda I$ = 3

We need to find jordan forms for $A,A^2$.

For $A$ its ok:

We have: 
$$
m(t) = (t - \lambda)^3
$$

Therefore, the charactaristic polynomial: 
$$
p(t) = (t - \lambda)^7
$$

And
$$
dim V_{\lambda} = 3
$$

Therefore: 
$$
G = diag\{J_{3}(\lambda), J_{2}(\lambda), \lambda, \lambda\}
$$

### NOW THE PROBLEM

Now i need to find jordan form for $A^2$.

The solution says: 
$$
P^{-1}A^2P = G^2 = diag\{J_{3}(\lambda)^2, J_{2}(\lambda)^2, \lambda^2, \lambda^2 \} = G'
$$

And then he says that the charactaristic and minimal polynomial of $G'$ are: 
$$
p(t) = (t - \lambda^2)^7, m(t) = (t - \lambda^2)^3
$$

And because $A$ is not nilpotaent than $\lambda \neq 0$ and we conclude: 
$$
rank(G'-\lambda^2 I) = 3
$$

How did he conclude all of that? we dont know that?

Its like he conclude that $A^2$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$ just squared.

But why? how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $Ax=\lambda x$ then $A^2 x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2 x$.

---

Updated: Clearly $(A^2-\lambda^2)^3=(A-\lambda)^3(A+\lambda)^3=0$. Now the multiplicity of $\lambda^2$ in the minimal polynomial [determines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82607/why-does-the-largest-jordan-block-determine-the-degree-for-that-factor-in-the-mi) the size of the largest Jordan block, which [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913128/jordan-canonical-form-of-a-squared-matrix) is of size $3$. It follows that $(t-\lambda^2)^3$ is the minimal polynomial of $A^2$.

Comment: RIght, thanks, and how do you conclude about the minimal polynom that its with the same power for example?

Comment: The minimal poly needs to divide the characteristic poly which doesn't seem to happen with the given information.

Comment: I did a mistake in writing and now fixed it, the idea is it for $A^2$ with the same degree as the original $A$ and i dont understand why

Comment: Can you quote the problem verbatim? It seems to me there is some mistake.

Comment: Its in hebrew...

Comment: OK (I don't know Hebrew). Can you recheck that the minimal polynomial for $A^2$ is $m(t)=(t-\lambda)^3$. Assuming the solution is right, since the roots of the minimal poly and the characteristic poly have to be the same this means $\lambda=0,1$. Now $0$ implies that the matrix is nilpotent, which is impermissible so we it would suffice us to establish $\lambda=1$. But I can't seem to deduce that.

Comment: You are right, i fixed it its with $\lambda^2$