# square root of invertible matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

For $F$ be algebraically closed field with characteristic $0$, how to show that for every $A \in GL_n(F)$, there exists $B \in GL_n(F)$ such that $A = B^2$?

$GL_n(F)$ denotes the set of $n$ by $n$ invertible matrices.

Comment: Not at all. It's false even for a diagonal 2-by-2 matrix with diagonal entries 1 and 2 over $\mathbb Q $.

Comment: I forget to say that the field is algebraically closed...

Comment: **HINT**: Think about Jordan canonical form.

Comment: do you mind explain how? I have absolutely no idea

Answer (score 2):

Here's an outline. First note that the fact that $F$ is algebraically closed implies that there are square roots in $F$. This immediately solves the question for diagonalizable matrices: If $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal, letting $B$ be the matrix $P^{-1}DP$ works, where $D$ has roots of diagonal entries of $PAP^{-1}$ on the diagonal.

For the slightly more subtle case where $A$ is not diagonalizable, we consider each Jordan block separately. Note that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 \\
  & & & \ddots \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\lambda
\end{pmatrix}^2 \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda^2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda^2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda^2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  & & & \ddots \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\lambda^2
\end{pmatrix}$$
for $\lambda \neq 0$. (see, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1849928/513190) answer.) By very similar reasoning to above, just with an additional change of basis, we get the desired conclusion.